# how to add two variables set by a constructor and use it inside a method

Tags: visual-c++

please forgive me if this is confusing because i'm new to c++(or any programming language really). i have this line of code in my assignment, but when i try to run the program i get an error at `(a+b).double()` saying no operator matches the + operand. I believe i did something wrong.

```
  #include<iostream>
  #include<math.h>

  class fraction {
  private:
    signed int numerator;
    signed int denominator;
  public:
    fraction(signed int a, signed int b);
    double getDecimal() {
        return 1.00*numerator / denominator;
    }
  };
  fraction::fraction(signed int a, signed int b) {
    numerator = a;
    denominator = b;
  }
  int main() {
    fraction a(1, 2);
    fraction b(3,2);
    std::cout << a.decimal() << "\n!" << b.decimal << "\n!";
    std::cout << (a+b).getDecimal();
  }
```

the `(a+b).getDecimal()` is supposed to return `2`.
how do i make the code work without changing the `(a+b).getdecimal()` part?

Answer (score 0):

> how do i make the code work without changing the `(a+b).getdecimal()` part?

You define the operator `+` for `fraction` operands, e. g.:

```
    fraction operator +(fraction b)
    {
        return fraction(this->numerator*b.denominator+b.numerator*this->denominator,
                        this->denominator*b.denominator);
    }
```